# C# WaitAny and missed event

Tags: c#, multithreading

When i using

```
int event_idx = WaitHandle.WaitAny(ExportEvents.ToArray());
```

and if event is in signaled state before `WaitAny` function calls then `WaitAny` function will:

1. result this event id immediately
2. skip this event and never result this id

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx):

> This method returns when any handle is signaled.

Notice is says it returns when a handle *is* signaled, not when it *becomes* signaled. That means if some handle is already signaled, the method returns immediately.

Of course, it's possible that a handle is in signaled state before the call, but it's not signaled during the call, due to a race condition.

Comment: I was going to ask this same question because I read the documentation as only guaranteeing that `WaitAny()` would respond to events set during the method call.  To me, "is signaled" could mean in the present tense (as opposed to "was signaled"); "signaled" being an act, not a state.  Also, in the current version of the linked documentation (emphasis mine) the method summary is "Waits for any of the elements in the specified array _to receive_ a signal." (present tense) and the sentence after the one you cite starts "If more than one object _becomes_ signaled **during the call** ...".

Comment: Now, testing with .NET Framework and Core, I see that `WaitAny()` does return immediately when passed a signaled event, and the "during the call" qualifier mentioned above seems to be unnecessary since it also works as documented when passed multiple events that are signaled _before_ the call.  What I'm still unsure about is if this is all due to implementation details or just unclear (to me, anyhow) documentation.

Comment: @BACON If you think the documentation is unclear, consider [creating an issue on the relevant repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of wait handle and if any other threads are waiting. If all the events have Manual Reset characateristics, then if result will be imedidiate. If there are Auto Reset events, and and another thread is waiting on the same events, it is a race to know which one will be signaled.